# let $\{a_n\} \downarrow 0$, show that $\sum_1^\infty a_n$ converge if and only if $\sum_1^\infty 2^na_{2^n}$ converge

Tags: calculus

let $\{a_n\} \downarrow 0$, show that $\sum_1^\infty a_n$ converge if and only if $\sum_1^\infty 2^na_{2^n}$ converge.

If $\{a_n\}$ is a non-increasing sequence, then this is Cauchy condensation test for [infinite series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test).

But the question says $\{a_n\}$ tends to $0$ from the right, and a sequence does not need to be non-increasing to tend to $0$, for example, $1/2, 1, 1/3, 1/2, 1/4, 1/3, \dots$ tends to $0$.
So how should I prove this statement in this case?

Comment: The theorem  assumes that $a_n$ is monotone nonincreasing to $0$. (that automatically implies that $a_n\geq0$). If there is a finite set after which the sequence nondecreasing, then for convergence purposes, you can neglect the first terms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notation $\{a_n\} \downarrow 0$ usually means that the sequence is non-increasing (and tends to zero).

The Cauchy condensation test does not work without the monotony condition: If you define $a_n = 0$ if $n = 2^k$ for some $k$, and $a_n = 1/n$ otherwise, then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^na_{2^n}$ converges, but $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ does not converge.